# MongoDB exact match on multiple document fields

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to build a Python script using PyMongo that will be able to hit a Mongo DB that can get exact matches of n number of objects that may exist in the database. Currently, I have this setup:

```
db.entries.find({'$or': [<list-of-objects]})
```

Where the list of objects looks something like this:

```
[{'email': 'some@email.com', 'zip': '11111'}, {'email': 'another@email.com', 'zip': '11112'}, ...]
```

Using `$or` works okay when I have 10 or so items in the list. I am testing now with 100, and it is taking a very long time to return. I have considered using multiple `$in` filters, but I don't know if that is the best option.

I'm sure there is a better way to handle this, but I am fairly new to Mongo.

EDIT: Output of `.explain()` below:

```
{
    "executionStats": {
        "executionTimeMillis": 228734,
        "nReturned": 2,
        "totalKeysExamined": 0,
        "allPlansExecution": [],
        "executionSuccess": true,
        "executionStages": {
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 43556,
            "restoreState": 43556,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "inputStage": {
                "needYield": 0,
                "saveState": 43556,
                "restoreState": 43556,
                "isEOF": 1,
                "inputStage": {
                    "needYield": 0,
                    "direction": "forward",
                    "saveState": 43556,
                    "restoreState": 43556,
                    "isEOF": 1,
                    "docsExamined": 5453000,
                    "nReturned": 2,
                    "needTime": 5452999,
                    "filter": {
                        "$or": [{
                            "$and": [{
                                "email": {
                                    "$eq": "some@email.com"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "zipcode": {
                                    "$eq": "11111"
                                }
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "$and": [{
                                "email": {
                                    "$eq": "another@email.com"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "zipcode": {
                                    "$eq": "11112"
                                }
                            }]
                        }]
                    },
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 208083,
                    "invalidates": 0,
                    "works": 5453002,
                    "advanced": 2,
                    "stage": "COLLSCAN"
                },
                "nReturned": 2,
                "needTime": 5452999,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 211503,
                "transformBy": {
                    "_id": false
                },
                "invalidates": 0,
                "works": 5453002,
                "advanced": 2,
                "stage": "PROJECTION"
            },
            "nReturned": 2,
            "needTime": 5452999,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 213671,
            "invalidates": 0,
            "works": 5453002,
            "advanced": 2,
            "stage": "SUBPLAN"
        },
        "totalDocsExamined": 5453000
    },
    "queryPlanner": {
        "parsedQuery": {
            "$or": [{
                "$and": [{
                    "email": {
                        "$eq": "some@email.com"
                    }
                }, {
                    "zipcode": {
                        "$eq": "11111"
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                "$and": [{
                    "email": {
                        "$eq": "another@email.com"
                    }
                }, {
                    "zipcode": {
                        "$eq": "11112"
                    }
                }]
            }]
        },
        "rejectedPlans": [],
        "namespace": "db.entries",
        "winningPlan": {
            "inputStage": {
                "transformBy": {
                    "_id": false
                },
                "inputStage": {
                    "filter": {
                        "$or": [{
                            "$and": [{
                                "email": {
                                    "$eq": "some@email.com"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "zipcode": {
                                    "$eq": "11111"
                                }
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "$and": [{
                                "email": {
                                    "$eq": "another@email.com"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "zipcode": {
                                    "$eq": "11112"
                                }
                            }]
                        }]
                    },
                    "direction": "forward",
                    "stage": "COLLSCAN"
                },
                "stage": "PROJECTION"
            },
            "stage": "SUBPLAN"
        },
        "indexFilterSet": false,
        "plannerVersion": 1
    },
    "ok": 1.0,
    "serverInfo": {
        "host": "somehost",
        "version": "3.4.6",
        "port": 27017,
        "gitVersion": "c55eb86ef46ee7aede3b1e2a5d184a7df4bfb5b5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the output of `.explain()`

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg see OP

Comment: The query is a bit inefficient, you are examining  5,453,000 of documents to finally get 2 documents.  Why not to create 1. create an index on any of the fields that contain high cardinality, it may be either the zip code or the email.  2.  using an aggregation pipeline, select the documents using the field that you used to create your index and then you have got to filter out a lot of documents using your new index.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Euclides, this data set will potentially get larger. Moreover, it won't only be just two objects; the two are just a snippet of 10k I am running as a test. Of course, as I add more objects to the or clause, this will get larger and be much less efficient. I am looking for a way to hopefully get around this limitation. You mention using aggregate, if you could help me build some sort of generic query that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid indexing and re-indexing (this query will not just pertain to email/zip, would be dynamic), I build the lists of data with each header and use them as `$in` arguments, then pass those into an `$and`. It seems to be working well enough and it hasn't queried longer than 3 minutes.

Example:

```
{'$and': [{'email': {'$in': ['some@example.com', 'fake@example.com', 'email@example.com']}, 'zipcode': {'$in': ['12345', '11111', '11112']}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create a new index (a compound index) as in your case you are using two fields for your search:

```
db.entries.createIndex( {"email": 1, "zip": 1} )
```

Now run your query appending the explain() command at your query, you should see that instead of COLLSCAN it has started to use IXSCAN.